# How to bring indices to the same index level

Tags: python, dataframe

I need to update annual_stats using an appropriate method which would bring year, state and salary to the same index level.

```
annual_stats = jobs.groupby(['year','state']).mean()
```

[image: dataframe]

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
annual_stats = jobs.groupby(['year','state']).mean().reset_index()
```